# No matching distribution found for selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to install `selenium` via Cmd using the command---- `pip install -U selenium` , but it's showing the error.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

See below details i am using python 3.5.1

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Anjali.Nautiyal>C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install -U selenium
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Anjali.Nautiyal>C:\Users\Anjali.Nautiyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
Python35-32\Scripts\pip.exe install -U selenium
Collecting selenium
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for selenium

C:\Users\Anjali.Nautiyal>python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is ur pip version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing python 3.5.1 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/)

Start a command prompt using the cmd.exe program and run the pip command as given below to install selenium. Try this and let me know if you face any issue

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium
```